# Google Cloud Messaging Returns 'to' on localhost

Tags: google-app-engine, curl, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, web-push

I am trying to send out a push notification through Google cloud messaging and using this as a guide

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/?hl=en

I get the endpoint from chrome but when I try to do a CURL call to the endpoint id (using my project number in the manifest file, and my api key), I don't get a meaningful message back. Not even a error.

All I get is 'to' as output. I am using CURL on Windows so I don't know if there is any additional info in the headers (is there?).

Has anyone any clue what 'to' is, and what can I do to fix this.

I am running this test on my localhost on an apache server.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide an excerpt of your code and a description of what you're actually trying to do, so we can help you. :-)

Comment: Is `curl` giving you 'to' as output?